# Can't install GNOME due to an unmet dependency on gnome-core

Tags: 11.10, gnome, software-installation, dependencies

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, then found that when I try to download the Gnome Desktop Environment from the Software Centre, I get the following message:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome
    Depends: gnome-core(=1:30+1ubuntu1) but 1:30+1ubuntu1 is to be installed.
```

I'm not offered the Gnome option when I right-click on the password screen.

I've tried the following commands, all gathered from the Web:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback restart
sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
sudo apt-get install gnome panel
```

None has had the result of allowing me to get and use the Gnome Desktop.  I'm a user, not a developer, and I only upgraded to 11.10 because I thought I would have that option.

What can I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 uses Gnome 3 by default. You probably mean gnome-shell, or are you trying to install Gnome 3.2 from a PPA or something?

Comment: Nick, did the below solution worked? I also suggest trying `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` first, then `sudo aptitude full-upgrade`, the last command will provide multiple solutions on how to solve dependencies problems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a shot at `sudo apt-get install -f`.  Should fix missing dependencies, although I can't be certain I understand the problem.

Hope it helps!