# Installed Kali Tools with kaltoolin3 on Ubuntu 20.04 and now Ubuntu will only boot to command line

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, 20.04, dependencies

Installed Kali Tools with kaltoolin3 on Ubuntu 20.04 and now Ubuntu will only boot to the command line.

Ctrl + Alt + F7 doesn't do anything. 
I've tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
but I get the error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: ubuntu-desktop-minimal but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
> ...........................Recommends: gnome-initial-setup but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I get the same type of errors when I try to install each of those packages individually.

I've also tried `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` and rebooting, but it goes back to command line.
`sudo startx` fails as well, giving the error:

> [xauth error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av2iM.png)

I've tried following the comments on [this page][2] to no avail.
Tried these commands with similar errors as above:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
```

... basically same issues as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605490/gnome3-isnt-installing-on-ubuntu-due-to-unmet-dependencies).

I tried the answer on [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625528/ubuntu-upgrade-leads-unmet-dependencies), again, no luck.

 Same [here](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/) too.

Comment: I should mention that I want to get back to the GUI.

Comment: If installing katoolin breaks your system by requiring wrong-version packages, then consider uninstalling it. A and B, from your output, clearly seem to be incompatible.

Comment: The Katoolin set of tools has been known to be difficult.  Moreso if you have done any upgrade since adding the sources for Katoolin.  [https://askubuntu.com/q/772495/283721](https://askubuntu.com/q/772495/283721)

Comment: What can I do to reverse this? There's nothing at /usr/bin/katoolin. I installed this from the /Downloads folder. I ran it again, and uninstalled all the Kali tools, sudo reboot took me back to the command line. Still no GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You have apparently broken your system, as referred to in the github page for katoolin3:

> Warning for Ubuntu users
>
> Installing programs from repositories for different operating systems
> is generally considered dangerous! Some packages might (and probably
> will) break your system. Be careful when installing the tools and
> don't blame katoolin3 for any inconveniences. The optimal solution is
> to install specific tools from tools.kali.org. It is not recommended
> to install all tools.

You could check this by asking what OS you are running (`uname -a`) but it is likely that your system is now a mix of Ubuntu and Kali, and unfortunately that don't always work in the way that either OS intends.

It is possible that with a some effort, you could get back to a stable Ubuntu 20.04 but the consensus of a search on this site for "remove katoolin tools" generally devolves into "reinstall Ubuntu"

Comment: :( I will be sure to use snapshots next time. I got a bit too cocky with the tool installs...